# Using a Class Based View (generics.FormView), how do I add form kwargs every time the view is used?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have a model `app/models.py`:

```
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
     my_field = models.Charfield(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
```

I have a form in `app/forms.py`:

```
from django import forms

class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.custom_data = kwargs.pop('custom_field', None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        fields = ['my_field']
```

And I have a CBV in `app/views.py`:

```
from django.views import generic
from .forms import MyForm

class MyFormView(generic.FormView):
    template_name = 'my_form_template.html'
    form_class = MyForm
    
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.get_form(**{i: want_kwargs_injected_to_form})
        ret = super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return ret
```

Basically I want to be able to add some custom fields from my abstract User model which the form requires. I dont want to have some crazy context overrides, I just want to ensure the form always has the extra data upon initilisation.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can't you just use `get_form_kwargs()` method? It should work for this view I think.

Comment: Can you give your answer in the context of my question as an answer please? Im not sure I understnad

Comment: completely unclear task, You want to have some additional fofmfield user model, you want to have initial data from user object in form? By the way - "dont want context override" - GCBV is always about overrides. Why you use FromView with model, and not the EditView?

Comment: It's not because Patryk answered the question, I simply asked him to expand on his answer with an answer to accept. As per https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/4.0/django.views.generic.edit/FormView/#get_form_kwargs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest Django approach is to override the `get_form_kwargs`:

```
class MyView(FormView):
    def get_form_kwargs(self) -> Dict:
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs["request"] = self.request
        return kwargs
```

Remember that you need to `pop` it in the `__init__()` of the form, before calling its `super()`.

Good luck!

Comment: Dunno if it was the good answer for @Swift but this saved my day. So long time looking for this solution ! Thanks

Comment: @Abpostman1 FYI:  I already knew the answer, which is why I phrased it in such a way, I wanted it to be answered this way so someone like you could find it. So I'm extremely happy that it helped just one person :)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add some info in form you can use `EditView.get_initial()`.

This is a dictionary.

```
def get_initial(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return super().get_initial(*args, **kwargs) | {'custom_data': self.kwargs.get('custom_field')}
```

after init everywhere you can use this initial dict:

```
 form.initial['custom_data']
```

You don't need to override form `__init__` or `get_form_kwargs` e.t.c.

Comment: Nope, check my other comment. The answer is clear my friend. Initial would populate the data in the form, as if that were loaded from the database, now, if that were from a blank object, perhaps that would be correct. And perhaps my question needs more context.

Comment: Sorry, but you are wrong. Initial can contains any Info. Of course in this case initial have data from database and you own data too. If you have something additional in initial data - the form not see it. But you can use it.

Comment: Sorry, but you are wrong my friend, read here... https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/api/#initial-form-values

Comment: And .... What is wrong in my sentence? I can add something in initial. I can use it in  form. Where is error?